# Corrupeted file when upload images using firebase storage in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, file-upload, expo

I'm facing a weird problem using firebase storage, this is making me crazy, im trying to upload a QR imagen with no luck.

I tried two ways, expo-image-picker using the path that comes when an image is selected, and taking screen shots with react-native-view-shot using the returned path, but the result is always wrong, a file is successfully uploaded in both cases to the storage but it goes "corrupted", the size of the files is always 9B

[image]

If i try to open the image a message is display "The format file is not compatible"

[image]

My firebase application is based on WEB

I'm following the official documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?hl=en

Here is the code

```
  uploadImage = async () => {
    var Transfer = 0;
    //const uri = this.state.selectedImage;
    const uri = URI.fromFilethis.state.selectedImage;
    const filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;
    this.setState({isUploading:true});
    this.setState({isTransfering:0});

    var metadata = {
      name : 'imagen',
      contentType: 'image/jpge',
    };

      var storage = firebase.storage();
      var storageRef = storage.ref(filename);
      var putFile = storageRef.put(uploadUri);;

      putFile.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
        var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
        switch (snapshot.state) {
          case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: 
            console.log('Upload is paused');
            break;
          case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: 
            console.log('Upload is running');
            break;
        }
      }, function(error) {
      }, function() {

        putFile.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
          console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
        });
      });
    console.log(
      'Your photo has been uploaded to Firebase Cloud Storage!'
    );
  };
```

Here are my dependencies

[image]

Here is the resulting path of image picker

[image]

Result path of view shot

[image]

All image references comes from the root of the device, im not sure if that has something wrong, any one can help me please ?